# Show Processing when loading image JQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, image-processing

I have an image being edited and reloaded with a new query string appened to make sure it doenst use cached copy . As Image already has an image source and when I change image user still sees old image and if image is big he might think that it didnt do processing . Is there any way to show user that image is being loaded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the initial image with a loading message:

```
function SomeImageChangeFunction()
{
    $('ProcessingImage').parent().text('loading...');
    $('ProcessingImage').attr('href', 'newURL');
}
```

The loading could be an animated gif or whatever you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jquery?

On change of the new image, hide it and show a div containing a loading image/text in the same position. Then, in the image onload, re-show the image and hide the div.

```
<img id="loadingimg" src="loading.gif"><img id="theimage" src="whatever-1.jpg" onload="imgloaded();" onchange="imgchanged();">

function imgchanged() {
     $('#theimage').css('display', 'none');
     $('#loadingimg').css('display', 'inline');
}

function imgloaded() {
     $('#loadingimg').css('display', 'none');
     $('#theimage').css('display', 'inline');
}
```